# Is it possible to run Istanbul from within code?

Tags: javascript, istanbul

Is there a way to run Istanbul programatically? I would like to trigger Istanbul from within a MeteorJS app. Istanbul's repo seems to suggest that it is possible through the use of their API, but I can't get it to work.

Does someone have a simple example of using Istanbul's API to generate the reports programatically?

Thanks

Comment: Ask directly here https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/